# How to export an Excel file from JSON with formatting and autofit using FileSaver.js

Tags: angular, typescript, filesaver.js

I can already export my JSON data to Excel with these functions:

```
  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string) :Promise<Object> {

    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    return (this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName));

  }

  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string):Promise<Object>  {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: EXCEL_TYPE});
    return await FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '-' + new  Date().toString()+ EXCEL_EXTENSION);
 }
```

But I can't figure out how to format this file, so I can at least have the bold header and the cells with autofit.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx), you can not achieve this without switching to PRO version which is quite expensive.

> This is the community version. We also offer a pro version with
>   performance enhancements, additional features like styling, and
>   dedicated support.

You can use [ExcelJS](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs) library. It provides styling free feature

```
 const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
 workbook.creator = 'Your company name';
 workbook.created = new Date();

 const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Worksheet 1');
```

then you can specify columns width:

```
 worksheet.columns = [
     { width: 15 },
     { width: 30 },
     { width: 10 }
 ];
```

you can make bold header using the following code:

```
worksheet.getRow(1).font = { bold: true };
```

specify cell styles:

```
worksheet.getCell('A1').border = {
                    top: ...,
                    left: ...,
                    bottom: ...,
                    right: ...
                };
worksheet.getCell('A1').font = ...;
```

and finally export file

```
import {saveAs} from 'file-saver';
const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';

...
workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer()
             .then((file: any) => {
                const blob = new Blob([file], { type: EXCEL_TYPE });
                saveAs(blob, `fileName.xlsx`);
             });
```

Follow this [link](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#styles) to find more styling options.